# w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind iptables fix - abusable?

Tags: network, firewalls, mod-security

It's only an idea. I've recently logged that my server is scanned by w00tw00t tools.

I found many solutions to this, such as use of **apache mod-security**, **fail2ban**, etc..

The one I want to speak about, is usage of **iptables** to block such IP's, based on apache log matching.

If I would use any presented idea, about how to block those scanning address, we must point out important fact, which is **requesting IP's are almost every time spoofed**, which means, they don't belong to attacker.

Isn't this idea then causing damage to our common users? If I would block out IP, which was spoofed by attacker, I would block someone, who is not causing me a real damage, which means, in conclusion, **none of the iptables based defense is usable**, or am I wrong?

Or worse, could this server-side preventive measure be used as attack? Such as If I need prevent somebody from accessing site, I will spoof his IP and get it blocked by this preventive system using **iptables blocking**, isn't it?

Study material:
http://blog.urlvoid.com/w00tw00t-at-isc-sans-dfind-web-scanner/
[https://serverfault.com/questions/125607/dealing-with-http-w00tw00t-attacks](https://serverfault.com/q/125607/86062)
http://profi-admin.com/Articles/Showfull/06/05/2010/Administration/How-i-got-rid-of-the-w00tw00t-entries-in-my-server-logs
http://foxpa.ws/2010/07/14/using-dfind-exe-and-blocking-w00tw00t-at-isc-sans-dfind/
http://www.myatus.com/2010/07/17/blocking-w00tw00t-scans/
http://spamcleaner.org/en/misc/w00tw00t.html

Comment: Related: [has my server been hacked w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind](http://serverfault.com/questions/281286/has-my-server-been-hacked-w00tw00t-at-isc-sans-dfind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP connections are not easily spoofed.  The reason for this is the [three-way-handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment) that must be completed before the connection is considered "established".  The connection must be established before an HTTP request can be sent.

UDP packets *are* easily spoofed but can't be used to attack Apache.

Since HTTP works over TCP connections, you can be confident that the IP address you are blocking is actually attacking you *at that time*.

An IP address that is attacking you today might be owned by a legitimate user tomorrow or even potentially at the same time if your legitimate user is infected and is part of a bot net.  It's worth making sure your firewall rules expire some time after the last attack was seen.

If you are particularly worried about false positives, you can create a custom 403 page that includes an out-of-band method of contacting you ( such as an email address or a phone number ) and then block the IP addresses using `Deny from 1.2.3.4` in your Apache config.